# Simple way to pass event arguments in "windows app" using MVVMLight

Tags: c#, mvvm, windows-8.1

I having an issue passing arguments from event(View/XAML) to viewmodel using MVVMLight. How do I pass event arguments to command? I currently using

```
xmlns:Interactivity="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity"
xmlns:Core="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core"
xmlns:mvvm="http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvmlight" 

<Grid>                
   <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>                    
      <Core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Loaded">                        
      <Core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ICommandLoaded, Mode=OneWay}" CommandParameter="{Binding args}" />
      </Core:EventTriggerBehavior>
   </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
<Grid/>
```

So in my viewModel, I have

```
public ICommand ICommandLoaded { get; private set; }
ICommandLayerLoaded = new RelayCommand(() => Grid_Loaded(null, null));
public void Grid_LayerLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{...}
```

How do I pass senderObject and RoutedEventArgs to my Grid_LayerLoaded class? Rather than setting it to null,null.

I come across this solution

https://marcominerva.wordpress.com/2014/01/10/windows-8-1-behavior-sdk-how-to-use-invokeaction-with-inputconverter-to-pass-arguments-to-a-command/

Is it necessary to create a converter for such simple task? Is there a better way to do it. (**Take note this is in windowsApp there is no EventToCommand**)

http://blog.galasoft.ch/posts/2014/01/using-the-eventargsconverter-in-mvvm-light-and-why-is-there-no-eventtocommand-in-the-windows-8-1-version/

Comment: Also interested in this. Seems like an awful lot of boiler plate to move a event command from the code behind into a bound object